# ReportViewer 2010, IO.Exception\

Tags: .net, report-viewer2010

I have an issue which I have concluded it is machine specific based, however I would like to know, how can solve it in case it comes up in another machine.

I have developed I WPF project  `(.NET 4)`, which I install using `Installshield LE`. prerequisites for the program is also ReportViewer 2010, which I install prior (if needed).

I have made installations of the program to following machines:

1. Windows 7 64-bit SP1
2. Windows 7 32-bit
3. Windows XP SP3  (case 1)
4. Windows XP SP3  (case 2)
5. Windows XP SP3  (case 3)

In all the above machines my reports run just fine, except #5 (case 3), where I get the following error:

```
 Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> 
    Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '' is invalid. ---> 
    Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. ---> 
    System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\<WindowsLogOnName>\Local Settings\Temp\expression_host_2e380b8068bb4ef5a53225faab4ebcb4.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

All the machines hit the same Data Base and the report I am testing is the same in every case.

Does anybody faced this error before and has any clue??

Comment: have tried clearing the temp folder and then running your Application again?

Comment: Would it be possible to install it in another folder? It often happens to me that I spend more time investigating CR issues like this one, than the time it takes me to develop the application.

Comment: If that is a database file try renaming the extension to something else.  Antivirus software will run checks on dlls new to the system and lock the file while doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard of malware and antivirus programs blocking access to the localreport temp files since the expressions within the report are basically VBScript. Try disabling these and trying again. [Here is the only source I have found on this](http://alsaydi.blogspot.com/2011/07/report-rendering-fails-in-local-mode.html).

Otherwise, a few things to try:

1. Check file permissions on both the RDLC and the temp files. The NETWORK SERVICES as well as the ASP.NET user account needs access to these. Make sure it has FULL CONTROL as it needs Execute permissions as well as read and write.
2. Check disk space
3. Try using a process monitor, such as Process Explorer, to see if any other programs are holding onto the file handle.
4. Try deleting the temp file and relaunching or recycling the app pool.
5. Maybe scour your event viewer to maybe find more info about the issue?

If none of this works, you may be better off reporting the issue to MS directly.